# How to share local server out to the public on Mac Sierra

Tags: macos, apache, server, port, web-hosting

I am planning to share out my local server to the Internet (not local Lan) for accessibilities around the world. I am stuck at this stage where by I have set up a local server and everyone in the local network is able to see what is on the web server using this machine's local lan IP address. I wonder how to make this local web server publicly available on the Internet?

Besides, I have a static IP address on this lan network, how can I make it point to my machine's lan ip? Also, how to open closed port 80 on this machine?

Thanks! My machine is Mac Sierra 10.12.2.